Error initializing int in unique pointer C++
If I initialize a unique pointer as below, I get an error:
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_obj=new int{10};


error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::unique_ptr’ requested

This code is working fine:
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_obj{new int{10}};

What is the difference between the two ways of initializing? Using {} and = should not make a difference as both are here explicit conversion to int only.

The former is copy-initialization, and requires an object of the same type on the right side (roughly), or at least a type that can be converted (and a regular pointer can not be converted to a unique one, an explicit constructor call is needed). The latter is list-initialization and can call any constructor instead. They are not equivalent in general.

Note you should use  std::make_unique<int>(10);

@PepijnKramer why?

@Ussu20 It does less work, and because of Exception safety. read exception-safety-and-make-unique. And if you are still in doubt, if the standard provides a function that can do something in one step there usually is a good reason for it ;)

to deal with the equal sign you must use std::make_unique:
 std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_obj = std::make_unique<int>(10);

and use it like a normal pointer:
 *ptr_obj; // return 10

your first try with the equal sign doesn't work because in left hand side you have a std::unique_ptr type and in right hand side you have a raw pointer of type int.
